# Initializing Spring bean from static method from another Class, giving method arguments?

Tags: java, spring, static, applicationcontext

How can you initialize a bean by using a factory method that needs a parameter?
I cannot find an example with a method that has parameter, only no params methods...
[spring docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-class-static-factory-method)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Care to scroll down a bit of the docs you gave?

```
<bean id="exampleBean" class="examples.ExampleBean"
      factory-method="createInstance">
  <constructor-arg ref="anotherExampleBean"/>
  <constructor-arg ref="yetAnotherBean"/>
  <constructor-arg value="1"/> 
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for :

```
<bean id="clientService"
      class="examples.ClientService"
      factory-method="createInstance"/>

public class ClientService {
  private static ClientService clientService = new ClientService();
  private ClientService() {}

  public static ClientService createInstance() {
    return clientService;
  }
}
```

Reference [1](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.RELEASE/reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-class-ctor)

Comment: It would be this if `createInstance` took an argument.